# using kustomize to modify nodeSelector's

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

It would be useful for me to be able to define at a higher level a way to determine a set of nodes that a set of pods should run ontop of.

Is there a way to use kustomize so that i can specify what nodeSelectors a deployment should have?

Answer (score 5):

OP asks for a way for all pods to run on a pre-defined set of nodes. So, adding to @yee379, you may define a patch to be applied to multiple generic resources at once like this:

```yaml
patches:
  - patch: |-
      kind: not-important
      metadata:
        name: not-important
      spec:
        template:
          spec:
            nodeSelector:
              key: value
    target:
      kind: (StatefulSet|Deployment|Job)
  # ... Include more resources
  # If you'd like to include Pods specifically:
  - patch: |-
      kind: not-important
      metadata:
        name: not-important
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          key: value
    target:
      kind: Pod
```

Answer (score 2):

i ended up just defining a patch:

in `kustomization.yaml`:

```
patchesStrategicMerge:
- nodeSelectors.yaml
```

in `nodeSelectors.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        group: infra
        slurm: mysql
```

bit long winded; but i guess it gives the most flexibility in terms of defining which pods i care ping and where.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can [tain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) nodes. This kind of nodes are reserved for specific pod.

Node affinity, is a property of pods that attracts them to a set of nodes (either as a preference or a hard requirement). Taints are the opposite – they allow a node to repel a set of pods.

Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. One or more taints are applied to a node; this marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints. Tolerations are applied to pods, and allow (but do not require) the pods to schedule onto nodes with matching taints.

Taints and tolerations are a flexible way to steer pods away from nodes or evict pods that shouldn’t be running. Here are examples few of them:

- **Dedicated Nodes:** If you want to dedicate a set of nodes for exclusive
  use by a particular set of users, you can add a taint to those nodes
  (say, kubectl taint nodes nodename dedicated=groupName:NoSchedule)
  and then add a corresponding toleration to their pods (this would be
  done most easily by writing a custom admission controller). The pods
  with the tolerations will then be allowed to use the tainted
  (dedicated) nodes as well as any other nodes in the cluster.
- **Nodes with Special Hardware:** In a cluster where a small subset of
  nodes have specialized hardware (for example GPUs), it is desirable
  to keep pods that don’t need the specialized hardware off of those
  nodes, thus leaving room for later-arriving pods that do need the
  specialized hardware. This can be done by tainting the nodes that
  have the specialized hardware (e.g. kubectl taint nodes nodename
  special=true:NoSchedule or kubectl taint nodes nodename
  special=true:PreferNoSchedule) and adding a corresponding toleration
  to pods that use the special hardware.
- **Taint based Evictions (beta feature):** A per-pod-configurable eviction
  behavior when there are node problems, which is described in the next
  section.

More information you can find here: [Kubernetes node for specific pods](https://medium.com/@alejandro.ramirez.ch/reserving-a-kubernetes-node-for-specific-nodes-e75dc8297076).

Interesting documentation: [taint-toleration-dedicated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.4/docs/design/taint-toleration-dedicated.md).